# How can I create a character who can assume the widest possible range of creature sizes?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization, creature-size

Just for fun, I want to create a character who can vary from really tiny or smaller to huge or bigger.

Which is the bigger/smaller combination to create that "Ant Man" style char?

It can:

- Be from any race.
- Be from any class.
- Use any magical-item combination.
- Use temporary buffs/magic, but only if can use it himself. (Don't need another player/NPC)
- Be level 20.
- Size changes can be in any form. Does not have to maintain original shape/race/type.

The more vanilla, the better.

Comment: Are you counting effects like Wild Shape and *polymorph*?

Comment: Does the PC have to stay in the same shape (example: begins as a dwarf, must look like a dwarf from largest to smallest)  or can the PC change forms?

Comment: It can be in any shape/form. It's more Antman like if it's the same, but I am only looking for the size.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## As a Moon Druid: all of 'em from Tiny to Gargantuan

You can cover all the sizes, and do so utilizing your own statistics by being a Circle of the Moon druid.

This works by activating your [wild shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#ClassFeatures), which provides that:

> Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast, but you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. You also retain all of your skill and saving throw proficiencies, in addition to gaining those of the creature. If the creature has the same proficiency as you and the bonus in its stat block is higher than yours, use the creature’s bonus instead of yours.

Unlike with *polymorph*, Wild Shape lets you be you...but in a different beast form.

### Get Gargantuan

At 20th level, a moon druid can transform into up to a CR6 beast. The one to pick  a CR5 [Brontosaurus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/brontosaurus)(nb: you will have to have seen one of these to do this), which is a **gargantuan** creature.

### Get Tiny

You've got a lot more options here with your Wild Shape and can pretty much pick [any from this list of tiny creatures](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-type=2&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-size=2&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=).

### *Shapechange* your way to it

The 9th level spell *[shapechange](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shapechange)* while at level 20 gives you full access to up to CR20 creatures, many of which cover Gargantuan and Tiny sizes.

> You assume the form of a different creature for the duration. The new form can be of any creature with a challenge rating equal to your level or lower.

Answer (score 6):

### A Druid 17/Wizard 3 will give you a lot of options

The key spells/features are:

- *Shapechange*: a 9th-level Druid spell which lets you change your shape to any creature, up to CR 20, as an action. (Concentration, 1 hour)
- *Enlarge/reduce*: a 2nd-level Wizard spell which lets you put your size up or down one category (Concentration, 1 minute)
- *Polymorph*: a 4th-level spell on both spell lists (we would know it as a Druid spell though) which lets you take the form of any beast (Technically up to CR 20, but the list stops at 8). (Concentration, 1 hour)
- Wild Shape: which gives you two uses to be a beast up to CR 5 (assuming circle of the Moon)

Notably these spells and features stack poorly, either requiring concentration or   Wild Shape preventing you from casting spells while transformed, but this will provide you the opportunity to transform many times (up to 1 *shapechange*, 11 *polymorph*s, 6 *enlarge/reduce* per long rest and two Wild Shapes per short).

Having the legendary [Staff of the Magi](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-the-magi) would add unlimited casting of Enlarge/Reduce. (Thanks NautArch)

What race you are doesn't matter much to this approach, but since you care about *size* you might want to be a Goblin for their **Fury of the Small** feature.

Comment: @NautArch I didn't intend for the spells to be stacked/ cast at the same time, but rather provide have more options so that you can change your size more _often_.

Comment: On the race front, you might want to consider Duergar as a stronger option. They get an innate once a long rest enlarge spell. Also Dwarf to Giant Shapechange seems pretty damned thematic for the Antman thing.

Answer (score 5):

### A range of Tiny to Gargantuan in two forms

To achieve this range, you will need the druid's level 18 Beast Spells feature and Combat Wild Shape, at least 1 level in sorcerer, warlock, or wizard, and a *staff of the magi*.

The two forms you will use are Giant Ape and Baboon (as these are the forms of appropriate size that have opposable thumbs).

- Tiny through Medium.

  - This is achieved by the Baboon form which starts as small
  - *Enlarge/reduce* cast at-will from the *staff of the magi* opens up the options of tiny and medium.
- Large through Gargantuan

  - This is achieved by the Giant Ape form which starts as huge
  - *Enlarge/reduce* cast at-will from the *staff of the magi* opens up the options of large and gargantuan.

Since *enlarge/reduce* requires no charges from the *staff of the magi*, you can switch sizes within the size ranges for each form as many times as you want within the maximum of 9 hours in Wild Shape. You can also switch size ranges once between short rests, making this character's size switching even more flexible.

For even more flexibility, you can also have access to...

- Small through Large

  - This is achieved by any medium race in your normal druid form.
  - *Enlarge/reduce* cast at-will from the *staff of the magi* opens up the options of small and large.

*Side note: As a high level druid, you would also have access to* shapechange *which offers a wide range of more powerful options for a short time in every size category*

Answer (score 1):

## Use the [Unearthed Arcana Mystic](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf).

This class has the Diminution Psionic Discipline and the Giant Growth Discipline.

Diminution gives you access to:

> ***Miniature Form (2 psi; conc., 10 min.).*** As a bonus action, you become **Tiny** until your concentration ends. While this size, you gain a +5 bonus to Dexterity (Stealth) checks and can move through gaps up to 6 inches across without squeezing.
>
> ***Microscopic Form (7 psi; conc., 10 min.).*** As a bonus action, you become **smaller than Tiny** until your concentration ends. While this size, you gain a +10 bonus to Dexterity (Stealth) checks and a +5 bonus to AC, you can move through gaps up to 1 inch across without squeezing, and you can’t make weapon attacks.

Giant Growth gives you:

> ***Ogre Form (2 psi; conc., 1 min.).*** As a bonus action, you gain 10 temporary hit points. In addition, until your concentration ends, your melee weapon attacks deal an extra 1d4 bludgeoning damage on a hit, and your reach increases by 5 feet. If you’re smaller than Large, you also become **Large** for the duration.
>
> ***Giant Form (7 psi; conc., 1 min.).*** As a bonus action, you gain 30 temporary hit points. In addition, until your concentration ends, your melee weapon attacks deal an extra 2d6 bludgeoning damage on a hit, and your reach increases by 10 feet. If you’re smaller than Huge, you also become **Huge** for the duration

You can spend 7 psi on a discipline starting at level 9. If you multiclass at least 3 levels into Wizard or Sorcerer (Wizard is probably better, since it's also INT-based, like the Mystic) or if you're a Duerger, you also get access to Enlarge/Reduce, although *you* can't stack this with your Mystic abilities, since both features require concentration.

To become small, you actually need to cast Enlarge/Reduce (Mystic can't do that), and to become gargantuan, you would need someone to cast Enlarge/Reduce on you or get an item that gives the effect without concentration (although no official item does this, to my knowledge).

---

**Do note that this class, while from an official source, is playtest material and therefore requires special permission from your DM to use. Regardless of your DM, it is not AL legal.**

Comment: I love this one, because you mantain your original form.

Answer (score -1):

## Depending on How You Read the Enlarge/Reduce Spell, Go Wizard (or Bard) for Absolute Gimmicky Extremes

As many have mentioned the Enlarge Reduce Spell, which wizards can get at third level, doubles or halves a creatures size. It is unclear however, so far as I know, whether it can double the size of a gargantuan creature or halve the size of a tiny one. The ambiguous parts of the spell read:

> ***Enlarge.*** The target's size doubles in all dimensions, and its weight is multiplied by eight. This growth increases its size by one category - from Medium to Large, for example.

and

> ***Reduce.*** The target's size is halved in all dimensions, and its weight is reduced to one-eighth of normal. This reduction decreases its size by one category - from Medium to Small, for example.

As you can see it has two direct size effects one of which (doubling/halving) has a straightforward game mechanic for any situation and the other of which (size category change) has no existing mechanic by which it can increase and decrease the size of a gargantuan or tiny creature respectively because there are no size categories beyond these. So essentially the issue is whether an element of a spell which, under casting circumstances, can not go into effect and has no provisions for this, nullifies the spell. This is open to interpretation, but if you are in the "it still works camp, proceed.

### Wizard for Double Concentration Glyph of Warding Shenanigans

Assuming the enlarge reduce spell does work to further the extremes of a Gargantuan or Tiny creature, you then need a way to both be the creature and cast enlarge/reduce on yourself (on the assumption that you're not really being Antman if someone else does the casting). Shapeshift permits you to cast spells as such a creature, but you have a Shapeshift with Enlarge Reduce double concentration issue, since they are both concentration spells.

There are few ways to do this, but a wizard can do it provided one spell is a creature targeting spell level 3 or below, via the Glyph of Warding Spell which is available to both Bards and Wizards. The relevant parts:

> ***Spell Glyph.*** You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower by casting it as part of creating the glyph. The spell must target a single creature or an area. The spell being stored has no immediate effect. When the glyph is triggered, the stored spell is cast. If the spell has a target, it targets the triggering creature. [...] **If the spell requires concentration, it lasts for the full duration.**

Thus with an hour of casting Glyph of Warding you can make that Glyph stored Enlarge Reduce, then use that one level nine slot to Shapechange (or True Polymorph) into the extreme-sized creature you want, trigger the ward, and enjoy one minute of absolute size absurdity.

This would also be achievable with True Polymorph, and thus a Bard, who gets that and Glyph of Warding could take Enlarge Reduce as a Magical Secret and achieve the same effect. Choice of spells (especially Magical Secrets spells) is a much bigger decision for a bard though.

Note: Originally Glyph of Warding seemed to specify that it was only a hostile spell against other creatures. This has been changed in 2017 errata as discussed [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115540/can-a-spell-with-a-target-of-self-be-stored-in-glyph-of-warding).

One should also note that, even if sizes beyond tiny and gargantuan are impossible, one could use these tricks with a halfling wizard to go straight from halfling reduced to tiny size to giant enlarged to gargantuan size, which is about as Antman-ish as possible.

Comment: I don't think there is an offiicial size beyond gargantuan or tiny. If you can support a size change there, that'd be helpful.

Comment: They do not exist, but I think I have discussed that exact issue as thoroughly as I know how though I'll edit to clarify that. It comes down to whether the lack of such sizes nullifies any or all other aspects of the spell. If anyone knows of any rulings, errata, answered questions, etc. on this point of spell effect interpretation that would be much appreciated.