# What are the targeting range limitations of Glyph of Warding?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, traps

[*Glyph of warding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) states, in part:

> When the glyph is triggered, the stored spell is cast. If the spell has a target, it targets the creature that triggered the glyph.If the spell affects an area, the area is centered on that creature.

[Other questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115540/can-a-spell-with-a-target-of-self-be-stored-in-glyph-of-warding) have addressed the fact that the specific wording of the *glyph* allows a spell that has a range of self, for example, to instead affect whoever triggered the effect.

My question is whether the wording also supersedes other potential issues- specifically, with how far away the target can be.

Can *Glyph of warding* alter the range of the stored spell? If so, by how much?

Answer (score 5):

### It's limited to the range of the spell

The [*glyph of warding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) spell description says:

> When the glyph is triggered, the stored spell is cast.

That's it: the spell is cast with all its normal statistics including range.

While the trigger of the glyph can be unlimited in range ("Trigger when I move 12,000 miles away") the spell that is cast is cast from the gylph with all its normal limitations.

Comment: Range is normally measured from the caster of the spell. Does Glyph of Warding say that the spell is cast from the glyph's position?

Comment: @MarkWells It says the spell is stored in the glyph, so I think it can reasonably be extrapolated that the spell is released from the glyph's position when triggered.

Comment: What about spells that have a range of self? Would those work with your "12,000 miles away" trigger?

Answer (score 0):

The wording is pretty specific as to what the target of the spell is, but the range to the targeting creature is left out on purpose, because it depends on the spell being stored.

The spell in the glyph is what determines the range. So if the spell was a single target spell, and the creature managed to trigger the glyph from outside the spell range, then the spell is cast but has no effect. If it was an AOE spell, then the spell would travel towards the target until it reaches its max range and then take effect. For a spell such as fireball, this could still potentially get the triggering creature within the AOE.

Comment: It would help to quote the bits of the spell you think say this. Answers need to be supported with something other than opinion.