# Can a bard who takes Contingency at 14th level use Spell Glyphs to Contingency-Revivify the party?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, targeting, traps

Here's the premise- Upcast your [glyph of warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) as a 7th level spell slot, select spell glyph. Trigger for glyph is "When [Desired Party Member] touches this glyph."

Cast [Contingency](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contingency)->[Revivify](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/revivify) into glyph, contingency trigger "when targeted creature dies." Desired party member immediately touches the glyph.

Contingency can normally only be cast on self, but Spell Glyph overrides that via

> You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph. ***The spell must target a single creature*** or an area. ***The spell being stored has no immediate effect when cast in this way.*** When the glyph is triggered, the stored spell is cast. ***If the spell has a target, it targets the creature that triggered the glyph.***

The last paragraph for Contingency says

> The contingent spell takes effect only on you, even if it can ***normally*** target others. ***You*** can use only one contingency spell at a time. If ***you*** cast this spell again, the effect of another contingency spell ***on you*** ends. Also, contingency ends ***on you*** if its material component is ever not on your person.

What we have here are two exclusionary clauses. The first is bypassed by spell glyph; the contingent spell can't normally target others, but spell glyph allows the spell to target others via means that *aren't* normal, and specific beats general. It's also worth noting that functionally, you are not actually casting the spell- you're storing it in the glyph and the glyph is casting it later.

Finally, casting a second contingency (which you effectively aren't during the glyph, because when you cast the spell into the glyph the spell has no effect- which would include the trigger effect of contingencies ending when the spell is cast- it does that *later* when the Glyph casts it for you) might be argued to end any contingencies ***on you***, but RAW does not end contingencies on ***other creatures***, which means if you deliver a glyphed contingent revivify to your party one or two people per day at a time, in a 4 person party on the 2nd or 4th day you could contingent revivify yourself, and the party would have 6/8 days of auto-phoenix.

Does this work or did I miss some glyph errata designed to prevent this beyond the 10 feet of movement bit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Probably, but this is a call for your DM

Both Contingency and Glyph of Warding break how normal spellcasting works, and consequently, there is heavy need of DM adjudication for them, as the rules only describe in detail how normal spellcasting works.

- **Contingency on another**. Contingency says:
  "*The contingent spell takes effect only on you, even if it can normally target others.*". The question is who is you in this case: is the spell limited to "you, the caster", or, to "you, the target of contingency". They normally are one and the same, but if you allow Contingency to be cast on another via Glyph, they differ. This is nowhere clarified in the rules, and so is up to the DM.
- **Multiple Contingencies**: One [can argue that there can only be one contingency at a time](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/203761/75095), because you means the caster, and Contingency states "*You can use only one contingency spell at a time*". On the other hand, one can argue (as you do), that Glyph overrides who *you* is, changing it to the target of the Contingency. This is the same ambiguity as above. This again will be a call for your DM.

For what it is worth, the consensus answer is that [you can store spells that target self](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115540/can-a-spell-with-a-target-of-self-be-stored-in-glyph-of-warding) into glyph, and have them work on others. That would suggest "you" in spells that target Self should be read as the target of the spell, not the caster of the spell, or they would not work as intended. Which in turn would mean that your scheme could work. But this is just an accepted consensus answer on the internet, not a rule or Sage Advice ruling, so the official rules tell us that it is up to the DM.

*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 5:

> Many unexpected events can occur in a D&D campaign,and no set of rules could reasonably account for every contingency. If the rules tried to do so, the game would become a slog. An alternative would be for the rules to severely limit what characters can do, which would be contrary to the open-endedness of D&D. Here's the path the game takes: it lays a foundation of rules that a DM can build on, and it embraces the DM's role as the bridge between the things the rules address and the things they don't.

(Funnily enough, here *contingency* is the contingency.)

Answer (score 3):

#### RAW, Contingency is unusable in a Glyph of warding...

As noted in [Ruse's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/203763/77044), the stored spell is cast when the glyph is triggered. This means that no matter how *Contingency* was cast to be stored in the glyph, a new, "clean" version of the spell will be cast upon triggering the glyph.

However, this means that the spell will be cast without a contingent spell to hold. This would effectively render this *Contingency* spell useless. It is unclear who the "caster" of the stored spell is, since *Glyph of warding* only specifies this (emphasis mine) :

> When the glyph is triggered, **the stored spell is cast**.

In normal circumstances, the caster would also be the target so there would't be any doubt. Here, however, the original caster and the target are two separate entities, which seems like a situation which was never thought about by the creator of the spell (or even intended in the first place).

So, reading the rules as written, you could store *Contingency* in a spell glyph, but it would do nothing upon being triggered.

#### ... but this is a boring interpretation.

In the end, it's up to the DM to decide how to rule this. They would be right in deciding this is an unintended abuse leading to casting a spell that was only intended to target "Self" on others, and disallowing it.

They would also be right in ruling it as you intended, meaning storing the original spell, or a spell cast at trigger time. It's up to whatever epic plan and situation you and your DM want to forge.

#### In any case, this seems unintended. Be careful.

Spells that target "Self" are explicitely designed on the premise that they cannot be cast on someone that is not the caster. Such an interpretation would allow to go around this limitation, which would land us in situations in which the rules were never meant to apply, just like this one.

This means that allowing the storing of "Self" spells in glyphs could have critical, unexpected side effects on the balance of those spells, possibly game-breaking. If your DM (or you, if you are the DM) decide to go this way, caution is advised, and the players should be aware of that.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your logic about it being unintended or not thought about, because spell glyph itself specifically goes out of its way to state that spells that can normally only be cast on self can be placed in the spell glyph and target other creatures. To me, it seems like this use was not only thought about, but explicitly intended.

Comment: @TheFallen0ne I double checked the rule text for both *[Contingency](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contingency)* and *[Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding)*, but couldn't find any explicit mention of targeting other creatures with Self spells. Could you please provide the quote you're refering to?

Comment: Ahh, that's my mistake. It's not explicit in those exact words. Relevant text is: 
You can store a prepared spell of 3rd Level or lower in the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph. ***The spell must target a single creature or an area***. The spell being stored has no immediate Effect when cast in this way. When the glyph is triggered, the stored spell is cast. ***If the spell has a target, it Targets the creature that triggered the glyph.***
Self spells target a single creature. If the spell has a target, it targets the creature that triggers the glyph.

Comment: @TheFallen0ne Self spells are often balanced partly by the fact they cannot be used on other creatures, so while this works as written, it seems like such a large buff to those spells that if it was intentional, it would likely be written as such. It's a shame there doesn't seem to be any Sage Advice on this case.

Comment: Choose a spell of 5th Level or lower that you can cast, that has a Casting Time of 1 Action, and ***that can target you.***
Self spells can target you.

Comment: I do agree that it's a pretty niche interaction. The only way it happens practically is if a bard goes out of their way to grab contingency. Wizards can innately get both spells w/o spending a magical secret, but can't get ahold of healing without some background/race shenanigans.

Answer (score 2):

### No, you cannot Revivify the *party*

You can Revivify one person.

> You can use only one contingency spell at a time.

When you try to cast this a second time, the first one ends even if it is held inside a *Glyph of Warding* or active on another PC. It’s still your *Contingency* spell even if it is affecting someone else.

Comment: But in this scenario is the caster using contingency, or is it "you" the target? Also, you don't cast spell into the glyph, you only *"store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph"*. Only *"When the glyph is triggered, the stored spell is cast"*. So no, spell inside Glyph shouldn't end because it didn't even start, it wasn't cast yet at all so how can it end?

Comment: Contingency isn't cast until glyph is triggered. Besides, "you" means "target", which by definition can only be you under normal conditions.  However, it is not clear to me how magic focus should work with glyph - I would've ruled that everything works and then Contingency fizzles immediately, because target is not in posession of the figurine material component

Comment: @Mołot “You cast that spell” is unarguably definitive

Comment: @Dartarian “You cast that spell” is unarguably definitive

Comment: Where is this "you cast the spell" taken from? What's the source? What I wrote is from the Glyph of Warding spell description on D&D Beyond. There's no "You cast that spell" anywhere on [Glyph's page](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding). Maybe you are using the wording that changed by errata as a base of your answer?

Comment: @Mołot misquoted. The correct quote is “… by casting it as part of creating the glyph“

Comment: Then the Glyph description is self-contradictory or the spell is cast twice, once by the original casting and once when glyph is triggered. If it's the first case, then DM decides and nothing is definitive. If it's the later, then yes, contingency from first casting gets cancelled, but DM decides if it really affects the second casting, and nothing is definitive, again.

Answer (score 2):

## Not quite

Crucially, when the Bard casts *glyph of warding* and *contigency*, the latter's effects **do not happen**. When another character triggers the glyph, *contingecy* is cast again and this time it takes effect:

> You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph. The spell must target a single creature or an area. **The spell being stored has no immediate effect when cast in this way. When the glyph is triggered, the stored spell is cast.**

Casting a Spell (PHB p202) explains what the effect of a spell is:

> Each spell description in chapter 11 begins with a block of information, including the spell's name, level, school of magic, casting time, range, components, and duration. **The rest of a spell entry describes the spell's effect.**

So in *contigency*'s case, casting the contingent spell, selecting the circumstance, etc. are effects, because these are laid out in 'the rest' of the entry:

> Choose a spell of 5th level or lower that you can cast, that has a casting time of 1 action, and that can target you. You cast that spell--called the contingent spell--as part of casting contingency, expending spell slots for both, but the contingent spell doesn't come into effect. Instead, it takes effect when a certain circumstance occurs. You describe that circumstance when you cast the two spells.

The contigency is a self-spell, which is eligible for *glyph of warding*, as you and [others](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115540/can-a-spell-with-a-target-of-self-be-stored-in-glyph-of-warding) have pointed out. But for any such self-spell to work at all as a glyph, the 'you' in the self-spell's description *must* be interpreted as the character that triggered the glyph.

This means that the character who triggers a *contingency* glyph is the one who needs to choose, cast, and expend a spellslot for the contingent spell, as well as choose a circumstance for it.

Moreover, it's the character that triggered the glyph who mustn't cast contingency again and who must carry the contigency's material component:

> If you cast this spell again, the effect of another contingency spell on you ends. Also, contingency ends on you if its material component is ever not on your person.

Notably, the material component of *contingency* isn't an effect, so it should match the character who cast *contingency* into the glyph, not the character who triggers the glyph.

### For example

The Bard casts *glyph of warding* normally and as part of that he casts *contigency* (using a statutte of himself as the component). The trigger he chooses is "when a creature picks up this statuette".
He repeats this process with a different statuette.

A Cleric picks up the first statuette, so *contingency* is cast, as if she cast it on herself: the Cleric casts revivify for the contingent spell with "when I die" as the circumstance. She keeps the statuette, else *contingency* would end.

A Fighter picks up the other statuette, so *contingency* is cast on her too, as if she cast it on herself: the Fighter cannot provide a contingent spell, so *contingency* fails. (She returns the statuette, breaking the Bard's heart)

Comment: I'm unsure about this interpretation. Glyph of warding states that you cast the stored spell as part of the creation of the glyph, and Contingency states that you cast the contingent as part of casting the Contingency spell. So if you cast Contingency for storing in a glyph, you should also cast the contingent spell as part of Contingency's casting. Not casting the contingent spell would make Contingency's casting fail, as you do not fit the casting conditions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141728/discussion-between-matthieu-and-ruse).

Comment: No, disagree. Matthieu is right; Contingency's spell text explains how the casting of Contingency works, not just its effects. "You cast that spell--called the contingent spell--as part of casting contingency, expending spell slots for both, but the contingent spell doesn't come into effect." The general definition of spell text as "effects of a spell" doesn't trump the specific wording of Contingency.