# What happens when Misty Step is put in a Glyph of Warding?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, traps

If *misty step* were put into a spell glyph using *glyph of warding*, what happens when it triggers?

- The creator of the glyph is teleported to the location set when the glyph was created?
- Whomever triggered the glyph is teleported to the location set when the glyph was created?
- Whomever triggered the glyph will be able to teleport as though they had cast the spell, choosing the location themselves?

Comment: I have to ask: so far you've asked three separate questions about three spells that teleport people being cast into glyph of warding. There's nothing wrong with that, but it seems like the preceding answers addressed at least part of this question (like whether the spell targets the person who cast it, or the person who triggered the glyph). Are you hoping to get a different answer for different spells? If you're looking for a particular result (e.g., how to teleport your character away in the event of trouble), you could ask how to do that: odds are good someone knows.

Comment: Related: [Who is considered to be the caster of the spell coming from a triggered Spell Glyph?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/113176)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## The creature that triggers the glyph will be teleported to a place the caster chose upon casting

Your second option is the correct one.

*Misty step* has a range of self, which means it only targets a single creature. As such it is qualified to be cast and put into a spell glyph.

As for what happens after it triggers, *glyph of warding* says:

> You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph **by casting it** as part of creating the glyph.

You cast the spell fully when you put the spell in the glyph which means you also need to choose the parameters of the spell, just as if you were casting it normally.<sup>1</sup>

> When the glyph is triggered, the stored spell is cast. If the spell has a target, it targets the creature that triggered the glyph.

Note that the creature who triggers the glyph is not considered to be the caster of the spell, it is considered to be the *target* of the spell. Essentially, the glyph casts the spell by proxy. Normally this means that the creature would have no input on how the spell works it would just receive its effects. The ambiguity here is that *misty step* has a range of self which means that normally, the only person who can be targeted by the spell is the caster.

In this case, however, *glyph of warding* overrides that and makes them the target of the spell even though they are not the caster. And, because the spell has already been fully cast, there is nothing else for them to choose.

Thus, they are teleported according to the conditions set on the original casting of the spell/glyph.

---

<sup>1 - This means you also technically would choose a target/area for spells in general when you cast them. However, after triggering, this is the one parameter that *glyph of warding* overrides.</sup>

Comment: Well, now I'm imagining a crazy boss encounter where the boss has set up a bunch of misty step glyphs around the arena to both aid their mobility and hinder/separate the party.

Comment: @RyanThompson Sounds like a Pokemon gym!

Comment: I am thinking of a boss who places these glyphs and teleports intruders into prison cells! lots of possibilities with this one

Comment: Does misty step normally require line of sight? Because this may be a way to sidestep line of sight...

Comment: So, say you place sigil on a rock and move it to another city. Does the spell in the sigil teleport you to the original destination set by the caster (more than 30 feet), does it teleport you 30 feet into that direction, or does the spell just fizzle as the target is too far away?

Comment: @MilanvanDijck you cannot move a Glyph without breaking the spell.

Answer (score 12):

### **Whatever triggered the spell will be teleported to a location set when the spell is cast**

Glyph of Warding says, under Spell Glyph:

> You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph **by
>   casting it as part of creating the glyph**.

...

> When the glyph is triggered, the stored spell is cast. If the spell
>   has a target, it targets the creature that triggered the glyph.

So you actually cast the spell at the time you put it in the glyph. The casting includes choosing a target destination. 
(It could be argued that the spell is cast a second time upon activation, but this never happens in any other circumstance, so I feel it's safe to say that this is not the RAI interpretation)

This question covers the same ground: [Who is considered to be the caster of the spell coming from a triggered Spell Glyph?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113176/who-is-considered-to-be-the-caster-of-the-spell-coming-from-a-triggered-spell-gl?rq=1)

Comment: Given that the range of *misty step* is self, is it even possible to store it in a glyph such that it could be activated by someone else? It seems ambiguous since "self" could technically fall under "a single creature or an area".

Comment: @RyanThompson how could self be interpreted as targeting an area?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I meant that the spell glyph option for *glyph of warding* requires the spell to target "a single creature or an area", and it's unclear to me whether that criterion is intended to include spells with a range of self, since it would allow those spells to affect other creatures.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose, likely: "Edited To Add"

Comment: @MarkTO I notice it is already been edited out, but note that you don't need to and shouldn't mark your edits. Just integrate them naturally into your answer.