Can a 10th Lvl Chronurgy Wizard use its Arcane Abeyance on a spell cast into a Spell Glyph?
(So far as I can tell, this isn't comparable to Wristpocket...)
In this scenario, let's say a 10th Lvl Chronurgy Wizard, casts Magic Circle into a Glyph of Warding spell glyph, & applies Arcane Abeyance to the casting of Magic Circle:
When a creature triggers the glyph, does that spell glyph produce a Magic Circle spell reserved for 1hr within an Arcane Abeyance bead?
I see a few limitations:
Any spell cast via a spell glyph, targets the creature triggering the glyph or an area centered on that creature.
A spell cast with Arcane Abeyance uses the Concentration of whatever creature uses the bead as an Action.
Would anything in RAW disallow this glyph-makes-bead combo? If not, then are there any problematic points a DM should be aware of before allowing it?

Err, should those links point to the questions instead of the answers?

The phrasing of the Chronurgy Wizard's Arcane Abeyance "when you cast a spell" is also used for Metamagic, so if Spell Glyph forestalls casting then Metamagic likewise wouldn't be usable at time of Glyph creation. (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113142) If Arcane Abeyance forestalls casting & not just effects, then... no glyph? (& no Metamagic) If the spell is cast during spell glyph creation & Arcane Abeyance can be applied, to recast or release the spell later, then... beware NPCs around Chronurgy Wizard lairs? I'm unsure whether to crosslink this QA, on the Metamagic glyph QA...

No.
This combo would produce:

a spell glyph that casts magic circle, and
an Arcane Abeyance bead that has no effect when activated.

From glyph of warding:

You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph... The spell being stored has no immediate effect when cast in this way. When the glyph is triggered, the stored spell is cast.

A spell glyph causes the spell cast into it to have no effect. It then casts the spell anew when triggered. Note that the text does not say that "the glyph releases the stored spell," it says "the stored spell is cast."
From Arcane Abeyance:

The spell is frozen in time at the moment of casting and held within a gray bead for 1 hour... A creature holding the bead can use its action to release the spell within...

Arcane Abeyance delays the effect of a spell until a creature uses an action to release it. However, a spell cast in the creation of a spell glyph has no effect, so activating the bead created in this way would also produce no effect.
As a side note, Arcane Abeyance does not directly modify the effect of a spell, so even if glyph of warding delayed the effect of the stored spell rather than casting it anew, there is still no way that a spell glyph could produce an Arcane Abeyance bead.

Welcome to the stack!

I think this may be the most correct answer, because the spell glyph captures a spell as it is being cast & "the stored spell is cast" later. Arcane Abeyance is used "when you cast a spell", but if the spell glyph casts X later then have you cast X? Yet, to create the spell glyph it says one must cast a spell, "by casting it as part of creating the glyph". "The spell being stored has no immediate effect." Both delays require that a spell be cast in order to use them; does either delay actually delay a casting, or only effects? Can we not Counterspell a spell being cast into a Spell Glyph?

Even assuming that neither Spell Glyph nor Arcane Abeyance preempt the Circle spell from being cast at their time of creation, I find the interpretation that Spell Glyph's effect would cause the Arcane Abeyance bead to hold a spell with no immediate effect, compelling & rather amusing; though I'm still not feeling confident about that answer either...

@ProphetZarquon "if the spell glyph casts X later then have you cast X?" Yes. The spell is cast twice: once during the creation of the spell glyph (with no effect), and again when the glyph is triggered.
"Both delays require that a spell be cast in order to use them; does either delay actually delay a casting, or only effects?" Spell glyph does not delay anything. It causes your initial casting to have no effect, then casts the spell again later.
"Can we not Counterspell a spell being cast into a Spell Glyph?" You can.

I agree that Spell Glyph unambiguously recasts the spell stored within it, & that Counterspell & Metamagic & Arcane Abeyance would each be usable upon that first casting; I like the reasoning that since the Glyph modifies the initial casting's effects to be none at that time, the Arcane Abeyance would have no effects of that casting, to store. Your last paragraph seems unclear, but otherwise I think this should probably be the most accepted No answer (& I suspect most DMs will want a No, even though as @ClericoftheWest & I covered, it's not especially OP & a Yes ruling also seems reasonable).

No.

You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph by
casting it as part of creating the glyph. The spell must target a
single creature or an area. The spell being stored has no immediate
effect when cast in this way. When the glyph is triggered, the stored
spell is cast.


At 10th level, when you cast a spell using a spell slot of 4th level
or lower, you can condense the spell's magic into a mote. The spell is
frozen in time at the moment of casting and held within a gray bead
for 1 hour.

Emphasis mine; in order to successfully cast a Glyph of Warding: Spell Glyph, you must store the spell as part of creating the glyph, which happens in the same casting action.
This is impossible in your setup, because the spell is instead stored inside the bead, rather than inside the glyph. You cannot store the bead inside the glyph, because until it releases the spell, it is not the spell.
Unable to fulfill its prerequisite of storing the spell in the glyph when you cast it, the entire spell fails, and the slot is wasted.
One might think there's a way around this by releasing the spell from the bead as you cast a glyph, since -

A creature holding the bead can use its action to release the spell
within, whereupon the bead disappears. The spell uses your spell
attack bonus and save DC, and the spell treats the creature who
released it as the caster for all other purposes

But this also doesn't work, since releasing the spell from the bead takes an action, and you must store the spell as part of creating the glyph, which means it must happen in the same unbroken casting as the action you cast the glyph with.

'you must store the spell as part of creating the glyph' this was one of my doubts. Yet, "When you cast a spell using a spell slot" & "the spell is frozen in time" & "release the spell" all imply a spell which has been cast, with Arcane Abeyance delaying the effects of the already cast spell; do you mean that storing the spell in the glyph will preempt one's ability to apply Arcane Abeyance? Based on your current answer, I don't understand how an effect-mod like Arcane Abeyance would preempt the glyph, since the glyph goes first. Would a spell glyph preclude any-&-all metamagic use?

@ProphetZarquon Any time you use Arcane Abeyance, the result is a bead. A bead can't be put in a glyph. The bead isn't a spell until you use your action to release it, it is a distinct object. Any iteration of events whereby a bead enters the glyph is impossible, because the glyph doesn't store a spell-turned-into-a-bead, it stores a spell. The context of the spell being frozen in time cannot ignore the rest of the feature specifically telling you that it is now a discrete, inanimate object rather than a spell, complete with AC and a hit point total until released with an action.

I don't see that it says it isn't a spell, it says it is a spell, which has been cast, & will be released from the bead; the bead seems to be an effect modification of the spell, rather than a discrete object that isn't a spell. I think your answer will be very DM dependent, because the words don't say the meaning you've described. Even so, I can see the reasoning; I'm just not sure the answer as currently written applies to the RAW.

@ProphetZarquon "The spell is frozen in time at the moment of casting and held within a gray bead for 1 hour." "and the spell treats the creature who released it as the caster for all other purposes."  While you may have "cast" the spell to put it in the bead, it is frozen at that moment. A creature uses its action to release it from its bead, at which point that creature is treated as if it had cast the spell 'for all other purposes.' That would, in plain english, also include for the purposes of when the spell is actually released or, "cast." (Fortunate for duration-based spells.)

Mmm, no, the spell's effects treat the creature as the caster "for all other purposes" but the spell is very much explicitly already cast & simply has its effects stored.

It should work as you described
Glyph of Warding:

You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph. The spell must target a single creature or an area. The spell being stored has no immediate effect when cast in this way. When the glyph is triggered, the stored spell is cast.

Arcane Abeyance:

At 10th level, when you cast a spell using a spell slot of 4th level or lower, you can condense the spell's magic into a mote. The spell is frozen in time at the moment of casting and held within a gray bead for 1 hour.

Both descriptions use the words 'casting' and 'cast' while not explaining the distinction.  My memory of grammar is that casting would refer to the process as it's happening and cast would be the entire completed action.  So, when you are 'casting' the spell into the glyph, you activate Arcane Abeyance as a sort of triggered reaction because the requirements are met.  When the glyph trigger is activated, the bead would pop out in the space of the triggering creature.
The process of casting this, according to Storing long cast time spells in a glyph, would go like this:

Begin casting Glyph of Warding for hour.
At the end of 1 hour, begin casting Magic Circle for 1 minute.
At the end of this, the final action is used to complete the casting, and the glyph is instantaneously inscribed, triggering the free action of Arcane Abeyance.

This wouldn't do anything special that you couldn't do with either feature individually
Since Arcane Abeyance only affects spells of 4th level or lower, the really abuse prone spells are omitted.  Plus, Glyph of Warding only applies to targeting single creatures or areas, so spells with a range of Self aren't possilbe.  The resulting list is large, but shouldn't break any games.

Indeed, I did specifically avoid citing a Self targeting spell, because at best that requires the glyph caster to be the bead user. So, a set of nine glyphs, could sit around for a century or more, then a creature triggering the glyphs could receive the Enlarge(/Reduce), & Dragon's Breath 4, & Earth Tremor 4, & Wither and Bloom 4, & Fly, & Galder's Tower, & Haste, & Greater Invisibility, & Polymorph spells, each castable for up to one hour, as an action? I asked about glyph-makes-bead because a ChronWiz doesn't typically get multiple beads & glyph doesn't typically have portable effects...

Each bead would use the concentration of the user, so each creature couldn't benefit from more than one spell effect that requires them to concentrate.  Compare that with simply casting the spells into a glyph without the extra step, and then immediately teleporting into battle, you could have all of those effects going simultaneously since the glyphs would do the concentrating for you!

This premise ignores two major points;
1: The spell you store must (spells only do exactly what they say they do) be stored in the glyph as part of creating the glyph, which occurs during the action you use to cast the glyph.
2: Point one is absolutely impossible to fulfill with the bead, because it takes a separate action to release the spell.

In this answer, Storing long casting time spells in a glyph it says "The secondary spell is cast as you are creating the glyph, not as you are casting the glyph. The glyph is a spell effect you inscribe after you cast the spell (it's an effect that can only come into existence as a result of a successful casting)." Which is what I based my answer on.

@ClericoftheWest My point regarding "anything special that you couldn't do with either feature individually" is that if this worked, a 10th Lvl Chronurgy Wizard could cache far more 3rd & 4th level castings than they'd usually get in a day, then pass around potentially dozens of them like candy to anything that can take an action (they'd usually only get ~1 bead per rest), while bypassing the no-moving-it clause of the glyph (if used within 1hr). Glyph would break action economy if it were trivially portable; this makes it slightly more portable. (L4 castings limited only by Material cost?)

What really worries me, is that the No answers contradicting you here, seem to contradict the answers to when\whether a spell has been cast, arrived at in other QAs... A lot seems to hinge upon whether a spell gets cast during glyph creation & bead creation, & until now the answers had said yes. If no, the spell is not cast during glyph creation, or no the spell is not cast during bead creation, then this combo doesn't work.

@ProphetZarquon I can think of a way to do pretty much everything you just said without the interaction in question, albeit at level 13 which is where the 200gp cost of glyph of warding is going to become a non-issue.  Store a tiny hut in a bead. Use right outside the boss room.  Teleportation Circle to your wizard tower, where youve stored 4 each of haste, fly, and greater invis in glyphs with the trigger being a spoken word.  Each party member activates all 3 types as a free action. Cast 7th level teleport back to your tiny hut immediately.  Proceed to curb stomp.

Yes, Spell Glyph already allows (albeit costly) buff spell storage, but some spells such as Wither and Bloom, Earth Tremor, & Galder's Tower (which can't usually be cast as an Action) are most useful with hostiles present, & the main limitation of Glyph is its non-portability, so I feel like any potential to add portability (such as openings to extradimensional spaces, or Gargantuan vehicles\creatures that are mapped so as to have locations which remain in place on them) is at least noteworthy. I agree this combo doesn't seem broken though. (assuming it even worked?)

@ProphetZarquon For clarity, my stance isn't that you aren't casting the spell; it's that when you cast the spell and use Abeyance, nothing happens from the casting of that spell, and it effectively stops existing, replaced by the bead, until you use another action to release it. This means that while you fulfill the trigger of casting a spell while you cast the glyph, your second trigger (the spell freezing and doing nothing until released) invalidates that trigger, in the same way that Arcane Ward invalidates the damage trigger for a Hellish Rebuke (b/c the ward preempts damage to the PC).

In the event that a spell is cast despite the two effect mods, I think Centricus' answer that the bead has "no effect" to store, makes about as much sense as I can hope for (at least from any No answers). By RAW, it seems all conditions for both delays are met; but the effects of Glyph seem to leave Abeyance with no "effect" to store at that time... It's janky, but still seems the most viable interpretation, among the No rulings. I'd still like a stronger case, because all 3 answers so far, seem very arguable. I'm not sure a definitive answer is possible yet, but these don't seem complete.
